# Paste0 working in Rstudio, not in Rscript

Tags: r

Have a string with some variables I need to pass to a loop that works 100% while in Rstudio, but gives me a:

```
"cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'"
```

When running in Rscript.

```
smalldata <- data.frame(V1 = c(1,2,3,4,5)

tablevar <- mondaysdata


sqljoin <- paste("select * from DBO.", tablevar, " p join DBO.TABLE2 l on (p.ID1=l.ID2) where p.ID1 =", "'", row, "'", sep = " ", collapse = ",")
for(row in smalldata$V1) {
  df1 <- as.data.table(sqlQuery(con, sqljoin))
  if (nrow(df1) == 0) {
    next
  }
  df1[,function1(.SD)]
}
```

Again, everything is working 100% in Rstudio and it is the same exact code, verbatim. I am calling methods at the top of the script. Smalldata is one column, 10,000 rows of ID strings. Tablevar is just a name we change based on the day.  E.g. mondaysdata, tuesdaysdata, etc.

Comment: You forgot to define `row` in your script

Comment: Not sure what you mean.  Row is defined with each loop.  It also works within Rstudio.  If that was the case would it not not work in Rstudio or Rscript?

Comment: Ugh. Yup, you're 100% right.  I can't believe I overlooked this for the past 45 minutes.  Put as answer and I'll embarrassingly accept lol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this line

> ```
> sqljoin <- paste("select * from DBO.", tablevar,
>                  " p join DBO.TABLE2 l on (p.ID1=l.ID2) where p.ID1 =", "'", row, "'",
>                  sep = " ", collapse = ",")
> ```

you use `row` before defining it. `row` is a function, hence the error message.